# android : remove border of share action icon

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I remove the white border of the share action, as shown in the image.

[image]

Here is my xml code for adding share action :

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="Share"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Java Code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchItem.setVisible(false);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    Intent myShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    myShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    myShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, ........ )
    return true;
}
```

I looked into the code of ShareActionProvider but was not able to figure out a way to change it.